# Manually accessing GMail via IMAP

Tags: gmail, imap

I'm trying to connect to gmail imap, but I am unable to execute any commands after login.

I'm running `openssl s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:993` to connect then,

```
* OK Gimap ready for requests from 128.146.221.118 42if6514983iwn.40
. CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA XLIST CHILDREN XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH
. OK Thats all she wrote! 42if6514983iwn.40
. LOGIN {email removed} {password removed}
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT LITERAL+ IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE
. OK {email removed} authenticated (Success)
. CAPABILITY
```

at which point it simply hangs with the connection open.  I'm guessing gmail pushes you off to a node in a cluster after it authenticate me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue. Use the -crlf flag. Pre-login, Gmail's IMAP server is less picky about the newline characters, they can either be `<LF>` or `<CRLF>`, but after you login, Gmail's server only responds to lines ending with `<CRLF>`.

According to [the IMAP spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501): All interactions transmitted by client and server are in the form of lines, that is, strings that end with a CRLF.  The protocol receiver of an IMAP4rev1 client or server is either reading a line, or is reading a sequence of octets with a known count followed by a line.

```
openssl s_client -crlf -connect imap.gmail.com:993
```

Answer (score -1):

imap server is async so add the below code

```
inbox = imapSslStore.getFolder("Inbox");
Thread.sleep(3000);
Message messages[] = null;
inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
Thread.sleep(3000);
```