# Access IMAP via OpenSSL

Tags: imap, openssl

I'm having trouble with (Gmail) IMAP Access via OpenSSL (1.1.1g)

I connect to the server using the following (see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/134924/manually-accessing-gmail-via-imap)):

```
openssl s_client -crlf -connect imap.gmail.com:993
```

Login works fine with the following command:

```
tag01 login s***@gmail.com v***
```

For some reason I can not use any other commands (e.g. `CAPABILITY` or `LIST "" "*"`) I always get an the error message:

```
tag02 LIST "" "*"
tag02 BAD Could not parse command
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the answer was fairly simple, I had to remove the [`-crlf`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/s_client.html) parameter, so the command to start openssl hast to be in my case:

```
openssl s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:993
```

I discovered that rather by accident, copying a command I used on a different server. Feel free to write a comment if you have other experiences.

Since I don't have enough time at the moment to dive further into this topic, I'll gladly accept a better answer if you know what exactly is going on in the background (especially if you know a way to figure out the right flags without using trail and error).

Note: A false `-crlf` flag used servers that are configured more strictly then google's IMAP doesn't even let you use the login command anymore (e.g. Strato returns: `. BAD [CLIENTBUG] Too many parameters`)

Note2: Don't forget to turn on IMAP and activate access for less secure clients otherwise you won't be able to log in.